# onVideoSelect vs onVideoSelected

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

in my react app, I have the following code in the component

```
<VideoList
      onVideoSelect={(selectedVideo) => this.setState({ selectedVideo })}
      videos={this.state.videos}
/>
```

The above code works, NO PROBLEM, but as soon as I change the *onVideoSelect* to *onVideoSelected*, I get an error that *onVideoSelected* is not a defined function.

My question is that **is onVideoSelected a function defined in ReactJS or ES6**?

FYI:

```
class VideoList extends Component {
    render() {
        const VideoItems = this.props.videos.map((video) => {
            return (
                <VideoListItem
                    onVideoSelect={this.props.onVideoSelect}
                    key={video.etag}
                    video={video} />
            )
        });
        return (
            <div>
                <ul className="col-md-8 list-group">
                    {VideoItems}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Other code:

```
const VideoListItem = ({ video, onVideoSelect }) => {
    const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

    return (
        <li onClick={() => onVideoSelect(video)} className="list-group-item">
            <div className='video-list media'>

                <div className='media-left'>
                    <img className='media-object' src={imageUrl} />
                </div>

                <div className='media-body media-heading'>
                    <div className='media-heading'>
                        {video.snippet.title}
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </li >)
};
```

Comment: First thing you need to share the relevant code. What is VideoList? Is it your custom component or a library? The code you shared isn’t enough to help with the fix. So share the relevant handler and state code in your component

Comment: Is `onVideoSelect` a property of the component VideoList?

Comment: Totally agree with @Think-Twice, please share some relevant code.

Comment: Done. Shared more code.

Comment: Do note that I was doing onVideoSelected throughout my entire code, ie, in all components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change onVideoSelect to onVideoSelected you need to pass to as onVideoSelected to VideoListItem component Like

```
    <VideoListItem
                onVideoSelected={this.props.onVideoSelect}
                key={video.etag}
                video={video} />
```

Now in VideoListItem onVideoSelected will work

```
     const VideoListItem = ({ video, onVideoSelected }) => {
     const imageUrl = video.snippet.thumbnails.default.url;

        return (
            <li onClick={() => onVideoSelected(video)} className="list-group-item">
               <div className='video-list media'>

                   <div className='media-left'>
                       <img className='media-object' src={imageUrl} />
                </div>

                  <div className='media-body media-heading'>
                      <div className='media-heading'>
                           {video.snippet.title}
                      </div>
                 </div>

              </div>
        </li >)
  }
```

Keep in mind that when you are accessing a function which is passed from parent. You need to access as it is the way you passed as prop